# IndexDWord Always Returning False for a DWORD pattern I know is in the buffer (FreePascal)

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Further to Marco's suggestion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018739/how-to-search-an-array-of-bytes-for-stringa), I have a situation where I have a buffer of raw byte data, 4096 bytes, read in a loop from a file.

I then want to search that buffer for a known hex string of 4 bytes. I have the following bits of code that compile OK, and I know there are bytes of data in the buffer, including the hex string I seek, but IndexDWord is always returning false (-1) and I can't see why. The odd "read then read again" behavior is because I need two seperate buffers - one contains raw byte data and one containing char data.

```
var
 Buffer               : array [1..4096] of char;
 Buffer2              : array [1..4096] of byte;

 const BinaryMarker : DWord = ($54435054); // (instead of Hex, Hex, Hex, etc. It now compiles)

begin
// Code relating to opening the file etc....then
   BytesRead := SourceFile.Read(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));         // Read a buffer as an array of chars
   SourceFile.Position := SourceFile.Position - BytesRead;       // Go back to where you just were
   BinaryBytesRead := SourceFile.Read(Buffer2, SizeOf(Buffer2)); // And read it again as byte buffer

   J := IndexDWord(Buffer2, SizeOf(Buffer2), BinaryMarker);
   if J > 0 then  // this is never true, even though I know the byte hex pattern exists in the buffer
     ShowMessage('Found at offset ' + IntToStr(J));    
end;
```

Help! I am using FPC 2.7.1 and Lazarus 1.1. The page for IndexDWord is [here](http://community.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/indexdword.html)

Comment: I see that you don't much care about feedback. Good luck! ;)

Comment: Hi TLama...things are going OK, thanks. Learning, slowly but surely, but no where near your league! I found the solution to this Q in the end but I can't remember off hand what it was and I don't think one is supposed to answer their own questions on SO? I will post the answer when I get home, if I can work out from where the question arose!

Comment: Thanks for (err, quite a late) feedback. Yes, you can surely [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: TLama, I don't understand. You didn't post an answer or even a comment, so why did I need to leave feedback. Unless I have missed something?

Comment: Yup. I've posted an answer to this question on Mar 21 '13 at 1:59 (which I've deleted about 1 hour ago). I've dropped a last comment asking for feedback there on Jun 12 at 9:15 (though there was more of them during a long time :)

Comment: In that case, I apologise. I didn't realise. And thanks for helping me out.